# pandas read feather ArrowInvalid

Tags: python, pandas, feather

When I'm trying to read a feather file I got this Error:

> ArrowInvalid: Column 0: In chunk 0: Invalid: Buffer #1 too small in array of type int64 and length 14712: expected at least 117696 byte(s), got 3450

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This file was created with another pyarrow version. I had version `0.17.0` and file was created by version `1.0.0`. So updating my pyarrow to new version solved the problem.